# WP7 Support TIFF images

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'm trying to display Tiff Images that I have a byte array for. I have come to the conclusion that WP7 does not support images which are TIFF, because setting the stream in the way I have done for PNG and JPG does not work (Throws an exception like: "`Network resource is invalid`").

Has anyone seen any evidence that TIFF is not supported in writing from Microsoft? I need to provide solid information to a client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Interoperability Bridges articles you can find this quote:

> Windows Phone 7 applications built
>   using Silverlight handle images in
>   JPEG or PNG format.

You can find this under *Other Issues* in the *Differences in iPhone and WP7 Image Resolutions* section in this article: http://windowsphone.interoperabilitybridges.com/articles/chapter-5-image-format-considerations-in-migration-of-iphone-applications-to-windows-phone-7

If that isn't official enough you can also find this quote:

> Silverlight for Windows Phone doesn't
>   support all image formats. The
>   BitmapImage class can be used to
>   reference images in the JPEG and PNG
>   file formats. For more information
>   about the types of image sources and
>   formats that can be used for an [Image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image%28VS.95%29.aspx),
>   see [BitmapImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage%28VS.95%29.aspx).

From the [AppHub](http://create.msdn.com) in their article about using images in WP7: http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/quickstarts/Images

Comment: Second link to AppHub looks great. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Neither the web-based Silverlight, or WP7 support TIFF images. However, there is a .NET library that others have fond relatively easy to port to Silverlight:

[How do I display tiff files on Silverlight?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379392/how-do-i-display-tiff-files-on-silverlight)

Comment: Thanks. I'm just looking for enough to tell my client to use .PNG, but i'll keep this in mind just-in-case.

Comment: Answers to the question you mentioned are a bit dated. LibTiff.Net supports Silverlight natively for almost a year now.